# how to find first non-empty by css selector?

Tags: css, selector

How to find the first non-empty child element  only using css selector?
Is there anybody who can help me? Thanks a lot!!!

Such as below:

```
<ul><li></li>...<li><span>o haha</span></li>...<li></li></ul>
```

How can I get the first non-empty li element by css selector

Comment: There's no pure CSS solution. I'd go with JavaScript: `document.querySelector('li:not(:empty)').style['outline']='1px solid green';` http://jsfiddle.net/qJ24r/

Comment: You get all not empty li with your code.

Comment: But you are right there is no solution with CSS selector. With jQuery something like `$("li:not(:empty)").first().css("outline", "1px solid green")` helps you.

Answer (score 7):

This needs two selectors to make it work:

```
li:not(:empty) {
   /* First non-empty <li> styles */
}

li,
li:not(:empty) ~ li {
   /* All other <li> styles */
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tr958/2/